# Is it possible to create a Custom Column that will take values from a specific view of a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a list of products that has two columns, product and product family.

I want to create another list that uses this first list as a lookup for one of the columns. This I can do, i.e. I create a custom column and then use the "Add from existing site columns" linko the "List Settings" page of the second list.

However, what I'd really like is that the custom column only proposes products that belong to a specific product family. I can create a View in the first list which allows me to display only the products in a specific family. However I don't see any way to specify only this view when I create the custom column.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Best regards,

Colm

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to make a dynamic select field that will populate based on what the user has chosen in a select field before it. You will not be able to configure this with out of the box SharePoint. It is possible to add some javascript to a form to achieve this. I believe you can also do this in InfoPath but I am double checking that.